# Add zero/zeros after fix characters, number of zeros vary MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've multiple records in a column and I need to add zero after a fix length, but the zero or zeros that we are going to add should check before adding how many numbers there are before adding zeros as it depends on numbers present
i.e.
I've this
A-0000-4438816,
B-1111-25654,
C-8989-36985217

in First record it has 14( **need to be 16**) characters so in the last section i.e 4438816 it should add **two zeros** and make it  A-0000-004438816

similarly for second record it has 12 characters, so in last section it i.e 25654 it should add four zeros and make it B-1111-000025654 similarly with other records

how can i achieve that and I've over 300k records in that column with similar situations

Comment: *"I've multiple records in a column"* columns don't have "records". Tables have rows and columns, but there is not such thing as a "record". What do you mean by this statement. Based on the latter part, are you implying you have delimited data in your table? If so, you should be fixing that first. Actual sample data (as DDL and DML statements, or otherwise tabular formatted `text`) and expected results will help us help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stuff()` for this.  To get the value in a query:

```
select col,
       stuff(col, 8, 0, replicate('0', 16 - len(col)))
from (values ('A-0000-4438816'), ('B-1111-25654'), ('C-8989-36985217')) v(col);
```

In an update, you can use:

```
update t
    set col = stuff(col, 8, 0, replicate('0', 16 - len(col)))
    where len(col) < 16;
```

Comment: When I executed this 


`update [TEMP_FormatBData_TX]
    set FullNumber = stuff(FullNumber, 8, 0, replicate('0', 16 - len(FullNumber)))
    where len(FullNumber) < 16;`

I got the following error 

`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 25
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Its was Varchar15 so I increased it to 16. Thanks for your help. <3

Answer (score 0):

I think padding zeros to the left is a way to solve your problem. sql has a function called *right* to do this operation. You can learn about *right* to understand it.

You can split your string using *substring* into two part.
From A-0000-4438816 to A-0000- and 4438816

and then use *right* function to pad zeros to the 2nd part.
4438816 to 004438816

and after that you can use *concat* to join both part to get the final and proper record.

I hope this will help you. Let me know if it's help.
Please feel free to ask if you need any more help. Thank you :)

```
select Concat(SUBSTRING(YourColumn,1,7),right('000000000'+SUBSTRING(YourColumn,8,LEN(YourColumn)-7),9)) as 'YourOutput' from YourTable
```

Comment: Add a brief description of the solution. Only adding code snippet is not enough